# How can I check if a directory already exists and if not, create it?

Tags: windows-7, sas, enterprise-guide

How can I check if a directory already exists and if not, create it?

I am using a SAS 9.3 server with SAS EG 5.1 under Windows 7.

```
%macro chk_dir(dir=) ; 
   options noxwait; 
   %local rc fileref ; 
   %let rc = %sysfunc(filename(fileref,&dir)) ; 
   %if %sysfunc(fexist(&fileref))  %then 
      %put NOTE: The directory "&dir" exists ; 
   %else 
     %do ; 
         %sysexec md   &dir ; 
         %put %sysfunc(sysmsg()) The directory has been created. ; 
   %end ; 
   %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(fileref)) ; 
%mend chk_dir ;
```

This code comes from the [SAS website](http://www.sas.com/offices/europe/uk/support/sas-hints-tips/ht1_mar04.html).

However when I try to create a folder using this macro, `%chk_dir(dir=E:\foo\20140904_test);`, it fails to create the folder and I get the following log message:

```
MLOGIC(CHK_DIR):  %SYSEXEC  md   &dir
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable DIR resolves to E:\foo\20140904_test
ERROR: Shell escape is not valid in this SAS session. 
MLOGIC(CHK_DIR):  %PUT %sysfunc(sysmsg()) The directory has been created.
```

The directory `E:\foo'` does exist and calling `%chk_dir(dir=E:\foo);` gives log output : `NOTE: The directory "E:\foo" exists` as expected.

Comment: I'm wondering if the following has something to do with this: http://support.sas.com/kb/41/058.html

Comment: Yes, you are correct: your server admin has likely disabled XCMD.  That is default, I believe (to disable it) so it may not be intentional - certainly worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may add

```
Options DLCREATEDIR;
```

to your code - this will automatically create folder if it not exists. Otherwise you will receive an error if you try to save results to folder that do not exist.

But this only solves saving, it doen't offer any solution if you just want to check.

Comment: This is partially correct.  This only applies to the libname statement.  Justin's not creating a libname in his code, so this doesn't exactly apply - although it does offer a solution (create a libname even if you don't intend to use it).

Comment: Now that is so hacky I almost like it... will test and report back